# SQL : Find the position of a character in a string value

Tags: sql, oracle, position, listagg

I have a column with below sample values

```
MyColumn
----------
NNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNN
NNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNN
YYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYY
YYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYN
```

I want to display the position of 'Y' through SQL select statement.

Below is my SQL query.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(instr(MyColumn, 'Y', 1, level), ' ') WITHIN
 GROUP(
 ORDER BY level)
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY level < instr(MyColumn, 'Y', 1, level) Y_Position from MyTable;
```

Output of the query is,

```
Y_Position
------------
6 7 13 14 20 21 27 28
3 4 10 11 17 18 24 25
1
1
```

The query is not working for 3rd and 4th rows. How to fix this? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query has invalid syntax as it has two `FROM` clauses one of which does not have a matching `SELECT` clause.

It also has:

```
CONNECT BY level < instr(MyColumn, 'Y', 1, level)
```

Which will not work when the string starts with a `Y` as `LEVEL` is `1` and `INSTR( 'YYYY', 'Y', 1, 1 )` is `1` and then the filter is `CONNECT BY 1 < 1` which is not true. You want to check that `CONNECT BY INSTR( MyColumn, 'Y', 1, LEVEL ) > 0`.

You also need another filter to check for the case when there are no `Y` characters as a hierarchical query will always return at least one row.

You can adapt your query to use a correlated sub-query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee617/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable( MyColumn ) AS
SELECT 'NNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'YYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'YYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYNNNNNYYN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT LISTAGG( INSTR( t.MyColumn, 'Y', 1, LEVEL ), ' ' )
                  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL )
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  INSTR( t.MyColumn, 'Y' ) > 0
         CONNECT BY INSTR( t.MyColumn, 'Y', 1, LEVEL ) > 0
       ) AS Y_position
FROM   Mytable t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee617/1/0)**:

```
|                Y_POSITION |
|---------------------------|
|     6 7 13 14 20 21 27 28 |
|     3 4 10 11 17 18 24 25 |
| 1 2 8 9 15 16 22 23 29 30 |
| 1 2 8 9 15 16 22 23 29 30 |
|                    (null) |
```